# Obtaining Euler-Lagrange equations for a mass attached to a spring, connected to a pendulum via a pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring, string

I'm trying to setup the Lagrangian for the following system, I'm quite confident this is correct, but I would like a second pair of eyes to analyse my solution. Here is the problem at hand

> A block with mass $M$ lies on a slippery horizontal table. The block is connected to a solid wall via a spring with spring constant $k$. From the block a thin, weightless and inelastic string is drawn over a weightless and frictionless pulley T.
> In its other end the string holds a particle with
> mass $m$, that can swing in a vertical plane. Set up Lagrange’s equations for oscillations around the equilibrium configuration, and solve them for the
> case of small oscillations.

Here is a sketch of the situation:

[image]

Note in the sketch that $\theta$ is omitted. Defining directions as in the sketch, and our first generalised coordinate $x$ as the distance from the equilibrium of the block, and our second generalized coordinate $y$ as the length of the pendulum, and finally $\theta$ as the angle of the pendulum with respect to the vertical, it ought to be the case that if the pendulum has equilibrium length $\ell$, $y=x+\ell$, which is a constraint for our system.

The position of the block is simply $\overline{r}_1=x\hat{i}$, and that of the pendulum is $\overline{r}_2=(-y\sin{\theta})\hat{i}+(y\cos{\theta})\hat{j}$. We could have ofcourse considered the picture differently to obtain $(y\sin{\theta})\hat{i}$. Now,
\begin{align}
\dot{\overline{r}}_2&=(-(\dot{y}\sin{\theta}+y\cos{\theta}\dot{\theta}))\hat{i}+(\dot{y}\cos{\theta}-y\sin{\theta}\dot{\theta})\hat{j} 
\end{align}
$$\dot{\overline{r}}_2^2=\dot{y}^2+y^2\dot{\theta}^2$$
Now, the potential energy of the system is simply given by (ignoring constant terms from gravitational potential)
$$U=\frac{1}{2}kx^2-mgy\cos{\theta}$$
Substituting $y=x+l$, one obtains
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}M\dot{x}^2+\frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot{x}^2+(x+\ell)^2\dot{\theta}^2\right)-\frac{1}{2}kx^2+mg(x+\ell)\cos{\theta}$$
which is how I would set up the Lagrangian. We then obtain Euler-Lagrange equations
$$m(x+\ell)\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta=\ddot{x}(M+m)$$
by taking derivatives with respect to $x$ and $\dot{x}$. For the $\theta$ equation, we obtain
$$-mg(x+\ell)\sin{\theta}=m(x+\ell)^2\ddot{\theta}.$$
Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through each step you've taken to evaluate the correctness of your approach.

#### Position and Velocity Vectors

1. You define the position of the block as ${r}_1 = x\hat{i} $. This is correct.
2. You define the position of the pendulum as ${r}_2 = (-y \sin \theta) \hat{i} + (y \cos \theta) \hat{j}$. This is also correct.
3. Your expression for${r}_2$ in terms of $\dot{y} $ and $\dot{\theta}$ looks appropriate.
4. Your expression for $\dot{\vec{r}}_2^2 $ is also correct.

#### Potential Energy ( U )

You define the potential energy ( U ) as
$
U = \frac{1}{2} k x^2 - mgy \cos \theta
$
This looks good, but it's worth noting that the gravitational potential energy is often written as ( -mgy ) where ( y ) is the height from a reference point, not ( -mgy \cos \theta ). However, if you're considering variations from the vertical position, then ( -mgy \cos \theta ) would be appropriate.

#### The Lagrangian ( L )

You express ( L ) as

$
L = \frac{1}{2} M \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + (x + \ell)^2 \dot{\theta}^2) - \frac{1}{2} k x^2 + mg(x + \ell) \cos \theta
$
It's generally okay, but I'd like to point out that:

1. The kinetic energy term for the block $\frac{1}{2} M \dot{x}^2$ is correct.
2. The kinetic energy term for the pendulum mass ( m \ seems to be correct too, as $\frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + (x + \ell)^2 \dot{\theta}^2)$ includes both the translational and rotational kinetic energies.
3. The potential energy term seems okay, especially if $\cos \theta $ is what you want to use to describe variations from vertical.

#### Euler-Lagrange Equations

You obtained:

1. $( m(x+\ell) \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos \theta = \ddot{x}(M+m)$
2. $( -mg(x+\ell) \sin \theta = m(x+\ell)^2 \ddot{\theta}$

These equations appear to be correct for your defined ( L ), but it would be helpful to go through the Euler-Lagrange equations' derivation step-by-step for better clarity.

To double-check your equations of motion, we'll start by using the Lagrangian you've provided:

$
L = \frac{1}{2} M \dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{x}^2 + (x + \ell)^2 \dot{\theta}^2) - \frac{1}{2} k x^2 + mg(x + \ell) \cos \theta
$

To derive the equations of motion, we'll apply the Euler-Lagrange equation:

$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i} \right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} = 0
$

where $( q_i)$ are the generalized coordinates. Here ( q_1 = x ) and $ q_2 = \theta $

#### Equation for ( x )

1. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} = M \dot{x} + m \dot{x} = (M + m) \dot{x} $
2. $\frac{d}{dt} \left( (M + m) \dot{x} \right) = (M + m) \ddot{x} $
3. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = m \ell \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos \theta$

Thus, the Euler-Lagrange equation for ( x ) becomes:

$
(M + m) \ddot{x} = m \ell \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos \theta
$

#### Equation for ( \theta )

1. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = m (x + \ell)^2 \dot{\theta}$
2. $\frac{d}{dt} \left( m (x + \ell)^2 \dot{\theta} \right) = 2m (x + \ell) \dot{x} \dot{\theta} + m (x + \ell)^2 \ddot{\theta} $
3. $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} = -mg (x + \ell) \sin \theta $

Thus, the Euler-Lagrange equation for ( \theta ) becomes:

$ 2m (x + \ell) \dot{x} \dot{\theta} + m (x + \ell)^2 \ddot{\theta} = -mg (x + \ell) \sin \theta $

After simplifying, we get:

$m (x + \ell)^2 \ddot{\theta} = -mg (x + \ell) \sin \theta $
It appears that the Euler-Lagrange equations derived from your Lagrangian are indeed correct. Your equations for $( x )$ and $\theta $ match the ones derived here, confirming your initial setup.